# Six seconds warmup time for the first entity framework 6 nonquery

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

From my integration test:

```
// Act
Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
w.Start();
userService.Create(userDTO);
w.Stop();


public void Create(UserDTO userDTO)
{
    var user = userDTO.ToEntity();
    _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

6,2 seconds to do an "sql insert" is crazy. I already see the application users complaining when they first open a project which they use the whole year. So everyday they have to wait 6 seconds...

I thought the warm up time in EF6 has improved?

Is there anything I can do to improve this miserable behavior?

Comment: Can you add SQL Profiler results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [EF6 CodeFirst View Generation T4 Template for C#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/18a7db90-6705-4d19-9dd1-0a6c23d0751f). Pre-generated views improve application start-up time by moving the work that would have to be done at runtime to design time. [more info](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/10/17/ef6-codefirst-view-generation-t4-template-for-c-updated-for-ef6-rtm/)

Comment: If I would still use the EF your advise would have helped at most. But I do not go down that route...

Comment: @Pascal - for 5 entities it should not make the difference (btw. I did write this template). Something else must be going on there.

Answer (score 5):

The time is not spent to insert a simple data. EF creates the model in the memory, that is where the time you spent goes.

EF creates Entity Data Model and executes View Generation(not db views) for the first time you do an operation on context. Have a look at [this blog post](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-improve-performance-of-entity.html).

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx) to improve the performance by using pre-generated views to decrease model load time.

To improve the performance you can initialize your context async when you start your application. Beware the multithreading issues.

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.Database.Initialize(false);
}
```

Comment: I use a DI framework to inject and control the lifetime of MyContext per http request. Thus I can not use your async advise it just does not fit. According to my scenario now do I understand you correctly that every time my DI tool creates the context per http request I have to wait 6 seconds? Lets assume I do not use compiled queries because my first statement is an insert/update...

Comment: Nope, it is for the first time your AppDomain is created. Context creation is cheap after initialization of EF.

Comment: So the EF initialization does not take place every http request?

Comment: It's initialized the first time you use the context (perform some kind of query, insert, etc).  The initialization is once per-app-domain.  Still kills startup performance and breaks development workflow though :(

Comment: @MertAkcakaya   Your answer is helpful. But your context.Database.Initialize(false);  seems to be a sync method. How can you initialize your context async? There is no InitializeAsync.

Answer (score 3):

Ngen will cut that in half.  Entity Framework is not compiled natively.  I have a script that compiles everything in the output directory.  Makes a big difference even when debugging.

```
    @ECHO OFF
    REM *********************************************************************************************************
    REM Compiles project's .net assemblies to native images to improve startup time and overall performance
    REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    REM Author: Brian Freeman
    REM History:
    REM     12/2/2013 Created
    REM *********************************************************************************************************
    REM Scenarios:
    REM     /Debug          - Generate images that can be used under a debugger
    REM     /Profile        - Generate images that can be used under a profiler
    REM     /NoDependencies - Generate the minimal number of native images
    REM                       required by this scenario
    REM Options
    REM     /verbose

    SET DEFAULTOPTIONS= /Debug /Verbose

    @ECHO. -------------------------------------
    @ECHO. Native Image Generator (Ngen.exe) 
    @ECHO. -------------------------------------
    @ECHO Current Defaults are %DEFAULTOPTIONS%


    REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    REM Small chance these might not be the locations of the .net framework
    REM Needs to be added to as the framework gets new versions
    REM ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    SET ngenx86=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe
    SET ngenx64=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe

    REM Run from the current Directory to ensure any dependencies are available
    pushd ..\DatabaseHelper\Bin\Debug

    REM SKIP vshost.exe
    ATTRIB +S ..\*.vshost.exe /s

    @ECHO. -------------------------------------
    @ECHO. Generator x64 Images
    @ECHO. -------------------------------------

    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir *.dll /b /s /a-d-h-s') do %ngenx64% install  "%%f"  %* %DEFAULTOPTIONS%
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir *.exe /b /s /a-d-h-s') do %ngenx64% install  "%%f"  %* %DEFAULTOPTIONS%

    @ECHO. -------------------------------------
    @ECHO. Generator x86 Images
    @ECHO. -------------------------------------

    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir *.dll /b /s /a-d-h-s') do %ngenx86% install  "%%f"  %* %DEFAULTOPTIONS%
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir *.exe /b /s /a-d-h-s') do %ngenx86% install  "%%f"  %* %DEFAULTOPTIONS%
    @ECHO OFF

    ATTRIB -S ..\*.vshost.exe /s

    popd


    @ECHO. ---------------------
    @ECHO. FINISHED
    @ECHO. ---------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried EF 6.0.2? It addresses several performance issues and may help. Find more details (including a list of bugs fixed in this release) [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/12/13/ef6-0-2-rtm-available.aspx)

Comment: I run 6.0.2 here and not change.

Comment: How big is your model? Have you tried running your app on EF5 to compare the start up time? If you have a stable repro you may want to create a bug on https://entityframework.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create - make sure to attach the repro.

Comment: 5 entities. There are many problems/inconvenient things I experience with my personal requirements with EF in general that I switched to ormlite servicestack after an evaluation of EF/dapper/ormlite :-)